# How to remove multiple patterns of special characters in Python Regex Dataframe

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

So I have a dataframe called `usa_sub_states` with a column called `'state'`.

In the column of `state` there are 5 states with non-alphabetic strings.

```
Massachusetts[C]
Pennsylvania[C]
Rhode Island[D]
Virginia[C]
Hawai'i
```

now I was wondering if there is a way I can replace all the special characters with empty string so that they all come out as a regular state name.

```
usa_sub_states.state.replace(to_replace=r'[\W]', value='', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

but for some reason this deleted all the content of the column and makes it an empty string.

Comment: Try `usa_sub_states['state'] = usa_sub_states['state'].str.replace(r"\[[^][]*]|\W", "", regex=True)`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pEY0Tp/1).

Comment: IT WORKED! TYTYTYTY

Comment: i just have a question though.

Comment: how would u write the syntax with the format

Comment: usa_states_sub.state.replace(to_replace=___, value=__, regex=___, inplace=___)

Comment: What is the problem? `usa_sub_states.state.replace(to_replace=r'\[[^][]*]|\W', value='', regex=True, inplace=True)`

Comment: Now I have another problem... every state with a space is now combined into 1 word..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
usa_sub_states.state.replace(to_replace=r'\[[^][]*]|\W', value='', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pEY0Tp/1). *Details*:

- `\[[^][]*]` - `[`, then any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `|` - or
- `\W` - any non-word char.

Comment: I just have one last question. So for some reason all the states with a space is now one word without a space. how can i avoid that?

Comment: @GirthyLampost Exclude the whitespace? `r'\[[^][]*]|[^\w\s]|_'`

Comment: I still get WestVirginia

Comment: @GirthyLampost Then it is your input. Or, there is some other code that removes whitespace.

Comment: okay i guess it has something to do with jupyter notebook itself but what i did was ran the cells one by one starting from a few cells up when the states had the special characters and what not and then it worked.